# How to solve and draw the graph of this function equation

Tags: functions

I see a graph of a function equation in the title page of [this book](http://book.ucdrs.superlib.net/views/specific/2929/bookDetail.jsp?dxNumber=000015584350&d=1A6EAD78EA78BA95F9700C890F09AED4&fenlei=13011007), but the specific drawing method is not given in the book. I want to know how to solve this function equation and draw its image:

$$f(x)+f(2x)+f(3x)=0$$

[image]

Comment: Could you write what is $f(x)$ ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici This is an equation for the function f, similar to this example: `WolframAlpha["solve f(f(x))=x", {{"SolutionAsAFunctionalEquation", 1},
   "Content"}]`. But I can't find one of its concrete expressions at present.

Comment: Interesting question. By eye and ruler some of the zeros appear to be approximately $0.6, 1.2,1.8$. Also $0.4, 0.8,1.2$. $f(0) = 0$

Comment: Also $0.2,0.4,0.6$

Comment: I guess they ( "the book people" ) chose an even function with some definition in an interval. Other values are found with the recurrence.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
I guess they ( "the book people" ) chose

- An even function.
- *Arbitrary* definition ( quite old "try and error" method ) in an interval.
- Other values are found with the recurrence.
  \begin{align}
  \mbox{Namely,}\quad\mrm{f}\pars{x} & =
  \left\{\begin{array}{lcl}
  \ds{\phantom{-}\mrm{f}\pars{-x}} & \mbox{if} & \ds{x < 0}
  \\[2mm]
  \ds{\phantom{-}x\sin\pars{63x^{1/7}}} & \mbox{if} & \ds{0 \leq x \leq 1}
  \\[2mm]
  \ds{-\,\mrm{f}\pars{x \over 3} - \mrm{f}\pars{2x \over 3}}&&\mbox{otherwise}
  \end{array}\right.
  \end{align}
  $\ds{\large\underline{\mbox{The Result}}}:$

[image]